# Error at Command Line : 5 Column : 84 Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma 00917. 00000 - "missing

Tags: oracle

```
INSERT INTO CAPDBO.NRP_BATCH_SCHEDULE_QUEUE (
SCHEDULE_QUEUE_ID,
SCHEDULE_ID,
SCHEDULE_NAME,
SERVICE_ID,
SERVICE_NAME,
SERVICE_PARAMETERS,
TIMEOUT_INTERVAL,
STATUS,
TRACE_ID,
ERROR_MESSAGE,
CREAT_DT,
CREAT_USER,
UPD_DT,
UPD_USER
)
values 
(
'capdbo.NRP_SCHEDULE_QUEUE_SEQ.nextval',
1,
'CAP_NFORM',
1,
'nrp-warehouse/capNformBatch',
accountingDate=TO_CHAR('YYYY-MM-DD'),
'YYYY-MM-DD',
600,
'PENDING',
null,
null,
to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-RR'),
'CAPDBO',
to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-RR'),
'CAPDBO');
```

> Error at Command Line : 5 Column : 84 Error report - SQL Error:
>   ORA-00917: missing comma
>   00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: `accountingDate=TO_CHAR('YYYY-MM-DD'),` ?

Comment: I think you just need to remove `accountingDate=` that's not valid syntax in a `VALUES()` clause.

Comment: After removing, I got the error

Comment: Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 20
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"

Comment: there's more values in the VALUES list than in the list of columns; i'm counting 14 columns and 15 values ....

Comment: INSERT INTO CAPDBO.NRP_BATCH_SCHEDULE_QUEUE 
(SCHEDULE_QUEUE_ID,
SCHEDULE_ID,
SCHEDULE_NAME,
SERVICE_ID,
SERVICE_NAME,
SERVICE_PARAMETERS,
TIMEOUT_INTERVAL,
STATUS,TRACE_ID,ERROR_MESSAGE,CREAT_DT,CREAT_USER,UPD_DT,UPD_USER)
values ('capdbo.NRP_SCHEDULE_QUEUE_SEQ.nextval',
1,
'CAP_NFORM',
1,
'nrp-warehouse/capNformBatch',
'asOfdate=TO_CHAR('YYYY-MM-DD')',
600,
'PENDING',
null,
null,
to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-RR'),
'CAPDBO',
to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-RR'),
'CAPDBO');

Comment: Error at Command Line : 16 Column : 17
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-RR'),  has multple problems.  sysdate is already a DATE, so does not need to go to to_date.  Doing so merely forces an internal to_char in order to create the proper data type for the explicit to_date.  And the 'RR' format mask was meant as a temp fix to buy time in resolving Y2k -- TWENTY YEARS AGO!  Long past time to abandon RR and RRRR and all use of 2-digit years.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO CAPDBO.NRP_BATCH_SCHEDULE_QUEUE
( SCHEDULE_QUEUE_ID
, SCHEDULE_ID
, SCHEDULE_NAME
, SERVICE_ID
, SERVICE_NAME
, SERVICE_PARAMETERS
, TIMEOUT_INTERVAL
, STATUS
, TRACE_ID
, ERROR_MESSAGE
, CREAT_DT
, CREAT_USER
, UPD_DT
, UPD_USER
)
VALUES
( capdbo.NRP_SCHEDULE_QUEUE_SEQ.NEXTVAL
, 1
, 'CAP_NFORM'
, 1
, 'nrp-warehouse/capNformBatch'
, 'accountingDate=TO_CHAR(''YYYY-MM-DD'')'
, 600
, 'PENDING'
, NULL
, NULL
, SYSDATE
, 'CAPDBO'
, SYSDATE
, 'CAPDBO'
)
```

Not at all clear what `SERVICE_PARAMETERS` string is supposed to mean, but in this SQL statement, it's just a string value. To included a single quote inside a string literal, the single quote can be escaped by preceding it with another single quote, e.g. string literal

```
'It''s fine'
   ^^
```

evaluates to  "`It's fine`"